# ¿Cómo puedo seguir registrando datos y guardarlos en listas si en algún caso no se lograra llenar una?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente código que usa listas para almacenar información:

```
#--Datos personales--
Lista_Nom = []
Lista_Ed = []
Lista_Est = []
Lista_Peso = []
Lista_Sex = []
Lista_Fch_Nac = []
Lista_Lugar_Nac = []
#--Datos de equipo--
Lista_Num_Rg = []
#--Datos condicion física
Lista_Act_F = []
Lista_Tem_Corriendo = []
Lista_Cal_Tiro = []
Lista_Ev_Comportamento = []
#--Datos de personas que podran entrar en el equipo--
Lista_Ap = []
Lista_Total_Rg = []
#______________________
Cant_ACT_F =0
#=====================================================
print("\n")
print("Cantidad de personas a registrar")
Cant_Per_Rg = int(input(">> "))
print("\n")
print("Registro de datos personales")
for xcprg in range(Cant_Per_Rg):
    print("Nombre")
    Nom_Per = input(">> ")
    Lista_Nom.append(Nom_Per)     
    print("¿Practica actividades físicas? [S][N]")
    Act_SN = input(">> ")
    if Act_SN == "S" or Act_SN == "s":
        Cant_ACT_F = 1
        print("Cantidad de actividades físicas")
        Cant_Act_F = int(input(">> "))
        for xcaf in range(Cant_Act_F):
            Lista_Act_F.append([])
            print("Nombre de actividad que lleva acabo")
            Nom_Act = input(">> ")
            Lista_Act_F[xcprg].append(Nom_Act)
    else:
        if Act_SN == "N" or Act_SN == "n":
            actfn=1
        else:
            print("Solo puede escoger [S] para sí y [N] para no")
    print("\n")
    print("Registro de rendimiento físico")
    print("Tiempo corriendo[min]")
    Tm_C = float(input(">> "))
    Lista_Tem_Corriendo.append(Tm_C)
    print("Califiación de tiro con pelota [1-10]")
    Cal_Tiro_P = int(input(">> "))
    Lista_Cal_Tiro.append(Cal_Tiro_P)
    print("Calificación de comportamiento con su equipo [1-10]")
    Cal_Comp = int(input(">> "))
    Lista_Ev_Comportamento.append(Cal_Comp)
```

Lo que pretendo hacer en pocas palabras es que cuando este llenando listas paralelas, no afecte si alguna persona no tiene lo mismo que la segunda. Es decir, si una persona si hace deportes pues que le aparezca la opción de para seguir poniendo sus diferentes deportes que practica, pero en la siguiente vuelta del bucle que si una persona no practica deportes pues que no le aparezca y siga. Luego, al final que haga el listado de todas las personas registradas con sus diferentes gustos de deportes y a los que no, pues que solo aparezca que no lo hacen.

El problema es que tengo un error

> IndexError: List index out of range

en a línea:

```
Lista_Act_F[xcprg].append(Nom_Act)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De verdad agradecería mucho que pudieran ayudarme, ya termine el tema de las listas en python y esta es la única duda que me queda :(, acabo de hacerme la cuenta en esta comunidad con el fin de poder buscar algún ejemplo de esto, pero no e encontrado o igual quizá no busque bien, pero igual. si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho.

Aquí el código completo por si fuera de utilidad :https://pastebin.com/BAkrww9r

Comment: Hola, creo que falta algo más e información para tener un [mcve]. Por ejemplo, ¿qué es y de dónde veine el índice `xcprg` y por qué añades una lista vacía en cada iteración del for a `Lista_Act_F`?

Comment: Gracias por tu atención de ante mano, este es el código completo: https://pastebin.com/60nshRGS

Comment: Solo que no quizá  ponerlo todo completo sería muy largo y quizá menos entenderían :(

Comment: Over.Stack, la idea es que se coloque un [mcve], es decir una versión representativa de tu código  lo más pequeña posible pero que reproduzca el mismo problema que el original. En su defecto, siempre es mejor colocar too el código que un fragmento que no sea comprensible por quien lea la publicación  por no tener contexto.

Comment: Eso si, nunca agregues código como imágenes, las imágenes en todo caso pueden ser un complemento, esto hace que el código sea muy difícil de reproducir, sea difícil de leer (especialmente en dispositivos móviles) y además no indiza para futuras búsquedas. Se que eres nuevo por aquí, no te abrumes demasiado, solo tenlo en cuenta y poco a poco irás comprendiendo como funciona el sitio.

Comment: He revertido a tu edición anterior en la que tenias el código como texto y he dejado la imagen de todas formas como complemento. Un saludo.

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias por darme estos grandiosos consejos y averme ayudado a resolver este problema. Tomaré en cuenta estos consejos para mi próxima pregunta y veré el archivo que adjunto, agradezco su atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como tienes estructurado tu código la idea sería que por cada persona la lista `Lista_Act_F` tengas una lista que contenga las actividades de esa persona. Si no practica ninguna la lista quedaría vacía o bien podrías asignar `None` a ese índice.

La idea sería:

```
# Lista nombres       # Lista actividades
[                     [
"Juan"       --->      ["baloncesto", "natación"],
"Pedro"      --->      [],
"Luis"       --->      ["fútbol"]
]                     ]
```

El problema es que asignas una sublista por cada actividad, en vez de una sublista por cada persona.

```
for xcprg in range(Cant_Per_Rg):
    print("Nombre")
    Nom_Per = input(">> ")
    Lista_Nom.append(Nom_Per)

    print("¿Practica actividades físicas? [S][N]")
    Act_SN = input(">> ")

    Lista_Act_F.append([])                            # <<<<<< aquí
    if Act_SN == "S" or Act_SN == "s":
        print("Cantidad de actividades físicas")
        Cant_Act_F = int(input(">> "))
        for xcaf in range(Cant_Act_F):                
                                                      # <<<<<< No aquí
            print("Nombre de actividad que lleva acabo")
            Nom_Act = input(">> ")
            Lista_Act_F[xcprg].append(Nom_Act)
    else:
        if Act_SN == "N" or Act_SN == "n":
            actfn=1
        else:
            print("Solo puede escoger [S] para sí y [N] para no")
```

Aparte de eso, al imprimir los resultados debes también modificar la forma como lo haces. Ten en cuenta que `Cant_ACT_F` es una variable que indica solo si **la última persona** agregada practica o no alguna actividad. Lo que debes hacer es usar el índice `xcprg` para obtener la sublista asociada a esa persona de  `Lista_Act_F` y comprobar si está vacía, si no lo está iteras sobre ella y muestras las actividades:

```
print("\n")
print("Registro de Jovenes")
for xcprg in range(len(Lista_Nom)):
    print("Nombre: ", Lista_Nom[xcprg])

    actf = Lista_Act_F[xcprg]
    if actf:
        print("Cantidad de actividades físicas que practica: ", len(actf))
        for actividad in actf:
            print("  Nombre de la actividad: ", actividad)
    else:
        print("No practica actividades físicas")

    print("\n")
    print("Tiempo corriendo: ", Lista_Tem_Corriendo[xcprg])
    print("Calificación de tiro con pelota: ", Lista_Cal_Tiro[xcprg])
    print("Calificación de comportamiento con su equipo: ", Lista_Ev_Comportamento[xcprg])
```

Dos observaciones:

- Te recomiendo que no uses mayúsculas para el nombre de las variables, por convención las variables y funciones/métodos se nombran en minúsculas con `_` como espacio, reservando las mayúsculas para las "constantes" (todo en mayúsculas) y las clases (CamelCase). Para más información:

  - [Guía de estilo para código Python - PEP 8 (recursospython.com - ESP)](http://www.recursospython.com/pep8es.pdf)
  - [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code (Oficial, ENG)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Probablemente la idea del código es hacer uso solo de listas, pero existen mejores formas de implementar esto. Una muy lógica es usar POO y una clase para representar a cada persona, no obstante, sin cambiar de paradigma un diccionario sería una opción mucho más apropiada y simple que tener una lista para cada atributo. Esto facilita mucho el acceso a los datos y su posible modificación futura.

---

```
registro =  []

cant_per_rg = int(input("\nCantidad de personas a registrar\n>> "))
print("\nRegistro de datos personales")

for _ in range(cant_per_rg):
    nom_per = input("Nombre\n>> ")
    lista_act_f = []
    while True:
        act_sn = input("¿Practica actividades físicas? [S][N]\n>> ")
        if act_sn.lower() == "s":
            cant_act_f = int(input("Cantidad de actividades físicas\n>> "))
            for _ in range(cant_act_f):
                nom_act = input("Nombre de actividad que lleva acabo\n>> ")
                lista_act_f.append(nom_act)
            break
        elif act_sn == "n":
            break
        print("Solo puede escoger [S] para sí y [N] para no")

    print("\nRegistro de rendimiento físico")
    tm_c = float(input("Tiempo corriendo[min]\n>> "))
    cal_tiro_p = int(input("Califiación de tiro con pelota [1-10]\n>> "))
    cal_comp = int(input("Calificación de comportamiento con su equipo [1-10]\n>> "))
    registro.append({"nombre": nom_per,
                     "actividades": lista_act_f,
                     "tiempo_corriendo": tm_c,
                     "cal_tiro_pel": cal_tiro_p,
                     "cal_comp_eq": cal_comp
                     })

# ===================================
print("\nRegistro de Jovenes")
for persona in registro:
    print("\nNombre: ", persona["nombre"])
    actf = persona["actividades"]
    if actf:
        print("Cantidad de actividades físicas que practica: ", len(actf))
        for actividad in actf:
            print("  Nombre de la actividad: ", actividad)
    else:
        print("No practica actividades físicas")

    print("Tiempo corriendo: ", persona["tiempo_corriendo"])
    print("Calificación de tiro con pelota: ", persona["cal_tiro_pel"])
    print("Calificación de comportamiento con su equipo: ", persona["cal_comp_eq"])
```